# Which implications are there for a quadratic form between being irreducible, non degenerate or smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, irreducible-polynomials, quadratic-forms, quadrics

Let $q(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) =\sum a_{ij}x_ix_j\in k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n] \; (a_{ij}=a_{ji})$ be a quadratic form in $n$ variables over a field $k$ of characteristic $\neq 2$, but not assumed algebraically closed nor anything else.
**Question I**
Are there any implications between the following properties?
a) The polynomial $q$ is irreducible i.e. it is not the product of two linear forms in $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$.
b) The quadratic form $q$ is nondegenerate i.e. its rank is $n$ [the rank  of $q$ being the rank of the matrix $(a_{ij})$] .
c) The quadric $V(q)\subset \mathbb P^{n-1}$ given by the equation $q=0$ is smooth.
Concretely c) means that the linear system of $n$ equations $\frac {\partial q} {\partial x_i}(a)=0$ has no solution $a\in k^n$ besides the solution $a=0$.
**Question II**
Is there a book in which these implications are spelled out?

Answer (score 3):

**About question I**

0. For $n=1$ all nonzero quadratic forms are nondegenerate, smooth and reducible.
1. For all $n\geq 1$ the properties "nondegenerate"  and "smooth" are equivalent.
   Quadratic forms satisfying these conditions are often called *regular* in the literature.
2. For $n\geq3$ these properties "nondegenerate" and "smooth" imply "irreducible" .
3. For $n=2$ the property "nondegenerate" (or "smooth") does not imply "irreducible".
   For example the form $x_1x_2\in k[x_1,x_2]$ is non degenerate but of course the polynomial $x_1x_2$  is reducible.
4. However  for $n=2$ "irreducible" $\implies$ "nondegenerate".
5. For $n=3$ the implication "irreducible $\implies$ "nondegenerate"  is false in general.
   For example the quadratic polynomial $x_1^2+x_2^2\in \mathbb R[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is irreducible but the corresponding quadratic form is degenerate.
   On the other hand the implication  "irreducible $\implies$ "nondegenerate" is true if $k$ is algebraically closed.
6. For all $n\geq 4$ and all fields $k$ the implication "irreducible" $\implies$ "nondegenerate" is **FALSE!**
   It suffices to consider the quadratic polynomial $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \in k[x_1,x_2,..., x_n]$ : that polynomial is irreducible over any field of characteristic not $2$, but the corresponding quadratic form is of course degenerate as soon as  $n\geq 4$.

**About question II**
No, I don't know any book nor any other document in which these (easy) results are explicitly spelled out. Does some user know one?
Since questions of this type often pop up (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3503445/3217), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1855508/3217) or [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1452443/3217) ),  I decided to try and give a reasonably complete answer.

Comment: I'm sure that (most of) these results are contained inside [The algebraic and geometric theory of quadratic forms](https://bookstore.ams.org/coll-56/).

Comment: @Eoin.  No, they are definitely not.  I challenge you to post the 7 page numbers corresponding to my 7 points. Anyway, I think a vague comment that ("most" ?) results are somewhere inside a 450 page book is not especially helpful.

Comment: 1903 answers and one question. good ratio. You might enjoy Classical Groups and Geometic Algebra by Larry C. Grove. everything relevant is surely in Lam, Quadratic Forms over Fields, but I don't remember answering any question on MSE by quoting from Lam. Also, as to my interest, he does not do spinor genus. He does do the spinor norm as a group homomorphism as Theorem 1.13 on page 108, in the chapter on Clifford algebras. Does not define genus, I guess that is what happens when the coefficients are in a field.....

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Will Jagy. I checked in Lam (whom I greatly admire) but could find nothing related to my question. Could you please give a precise reference?

Comment: 0. Proposition 7.19 on p. 43 (nondegenerate), Remark 7.20 on p. 44 (regular), this is a stretch but Corollary 7.30 on p. 45 and Notation 7.3 on p. 40 (reducible)
1. Proposition 22.1 on p. 93
2. Page 94
3. If n=2, then nondegenerate does not imply irreducible (an isotropic nondegenerate form of dimension 2 is a hyperbolic plane, Proposition 7.13, e.g. xy Example 7.5).
4. Page 93 (an irreducible quadric of dimension 0 is a point)
I don't know if I can find 5 or 6 but, I didn't claim to be able to either.

Comment: Georges, now that I have printed out the three past questions, I think my contribution to the discussion is my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  and my answer. Evidently the method I settled on is taught in some countries in college. I went as far as writing a C++ program that begins with inputting a symmetric matrix $H$ of (rational) integers. It produces rational matrices $P,Q,D$ of determinant $\pm 1$ with $PQ=QP = I$ and $D$ diagonal, then $P^TH P = D$ and $Q^T DQ = H.$

Comment: $$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$    Output is in Latex code suitable for MSE.

Comment: $$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
3 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 4 & 5 \\ 
3 & 5 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: @Eoin. Of course everything I wrote can be deduced from the extremely advanced book you mention. **Every question** on this site, which is not a research journal and contains no original result, has its answer in some  book.  My aim was to have a concise summing up of the main relations between the properties I examine. You got 23 upvotes for proving that [the image of a pathwise connected space under a continuous map is pathwise connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1251927/3217). Is that stated in no book? Did somebody comment "I'm sure that this is contained in Bourbaki's Topology" ?

Comment: @Georges No, of course the post of mine that you cite is in a number of books or notes on topology. I also don't know what information the OP has to ask this question; I was only providing a reference that the OP could look to if they were trying to find more about the subject and your examples. Lam's book was another that I thought could be a good reference. (Both of these though are really just comments).

Comment: @Eoin. Ok, I think we can agree on your last comment.